# Issue returning single row from active record query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following query, in Code Igniter active records:

```
    $this->db->select('overflow');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('raffles', array('lottery_id' => $lottery_id));
    var_dump($query->first_row()->overflow);
    exit;
```

However, I get the following error when attempting var_dump the singe row:

> Trying to get property of non-object

This does look like valid code to me however, can anyone spot the issue?

Comment: Are you sure about your query ? Is $loterry_id exists in your DB ?

Comment: Just remove `$this->db->select('overflow');` from your code!! By using `get_where` you will get all data from your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->select(*);
$query = $this->db->get_where('raffles', array('lottery_id' => $lottery_id));
$row = $query->first_row('array'); # Changed
print_r($row); # Added
```

> **By default they return an object unless you put the word "array" in the parameter**